# How to show quantity in dropdown in product page and cart page magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.1

I just want to show quantity in dropdown for simple and configurable products in product view page and cart page as well.

I replace code in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml` page

Replace below code

```
<input class="qty-decrease" value="-" type="button" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) && qty > 1 ) qty_el.value--;return false;">
            <input id="qty" class="input-text qty" type="text" maxlength="12" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" size="4" value="1" name="qty" style="padding-top: 0;">
<input class="qty-increase"  value="+" type="button" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) qty_el.value++;return false;">
```

to

```
<select class="input-text qty" name="qty" id="qty">
<?php $i = 1 ?>
<?php do { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $i?>">
<?php echo $i?>
<?php $i++ ?>
</option>
<?php } while ($i <= (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()) ?>
</select>
```

It is working fine for simple product but in configurable product, options are not showing. And in cart page I am unable to see anything for both types of products.

Answer (score 0):

In configurable product **qty is not their own**, In configurable product **qty come from associated product** so you have to put condition for configurable product if configurable product found then you have to get qty from their associated product instead of configurable product.

Comment: I have to developed that code so try by your self, if still face problem let me know. make you sure that one configurable product has multiple associated product so you have to apply your logic that which product qty you want show or you can sum associated product qty.

Comment: I have tried a lot from my end. So it would be better if you will send your code. Thanks

Comment: I hope you very well know how to do loop using this products and get some of all item qty and display in dropdown
`$ids=Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
            ->getChildrenIds($configurable_product_id);
      $_subproducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addIdFilter ($ids);
// get qty for each product
$product->getStockItem()->getQty();`